# lexical scope, what about side by side?

Tags: javascript

Articles I've read on scope in javascript address what happens when you have nested variables/objects/functions defined in its parent scope. However, what happens if you have something like this:

```
function x(){

function y(){var u = 3;}
function z(){//is u available here?}

}
```

Comment: Omitting newlines isn't going to affect the scope... And no, `u` is not accessible there (which you could have found out yourself in 4 seconds).

Comment: did u check it? was u available.i guess not

Comment: i tried putting it in fiddle but it wasn't working...

Comment: [It's working OK for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/dd5apuad/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a question which could be easily answered with a one-second test.

Comment: @torazaburo—if the OP doesn't know that, then they require more than a yes or no answer.

Comment: The fiddle is not working for me.. what's wrong?

Comment: @slynthin If you see "'u' is undefined" in the console log, then that means that the Fiddle is working.

Answer (score -1):

var u in function y is not available in function z. However it will be accessible in you omit the var.

```
u = 3; // instead of var u = 3;
```

omitting the "var" will make the variable global.

Comment: It should be avoided of omitting the "var"

Comment: I agree. I just mentioned it for the sake of the discussion about scope. :)

Comment: *u* is only global after the code assigning to it executes, before then it's not defined. Maybe mention strict mode restrictions?